# Finite State Machine in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fsm, vivado

For a project I'm making a PWM multiplexer but no succes with my FSM. When I receive an interrupt of PWM_INT the counter should increment or go to 0 if max is reached. The counter depends the state of the FSM.

This is my implementation:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Mux is
    Port ( CLK      : in STD_LOGIC;
           RST      : in STD_LOGIC;
           PWM      : in STD_LOGIC;
           PWM_INT  : in STD_LOGIC;
           PWM_A    : out STD_LOGIC;
           PWM_B    : out STD_LOGIC;
           PWM_C    : out STD_LOGIC);
end Mux;

architecture Behavioral of Mux is
type state is (iddle,state_1,state_2,state_3,state_4,state_5,state_6,new_fsm);

signal old_state    :   state   ;
signal new_state    :   state   ;
signal counter      : integer range 6 downto 0; 

begin
    process(CLK)
        begin
            if RST = '1' then
                counter <= 0;
                PWM_A <= '0';
                PWM_B <= '0';
                PWM_C <= '0';                
            elsif CLK'event and CLK = '1' then
                if PWM_INT = '1' then
                    if counter < 6 then
                        counter <= counter + 1;
                    else
                        counter <= 0;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if; 
    end process;

----- Clocked Process FSM -----
    process(CLK)
        begin
            if RST = '1' then
                old_state <= iddle;
            elsif (CLK'event and CLK = '1') then
                old_state <= new_state;
            end if; 
    end process;

----- Transitions -----
    process(old_state,counter)
        begin
            case old_state is
                when iddle      =>      if counter = 0 then
                                            new_state <= state_1;
                                        else
                                            new_state <= iddle;
                                        end if;

                when state_1    =>      if counter = 1 then
                                            new_state <= state_2;
                                        else
                                            new_state <= state_1;    
                                        end if;

                when state_2    =>      if counter = 2 then
                                            new_state <= state_3;
                                        else
                                            new_state <= state_2;
                                        end if;

                when state_3    =>      if counter = 3 then
                                            new_state <= state_4;
                                        else
                                            new_state <= state_3;
                                        end if;

                when state_4    =>      if counter = 4 then
                                            new_state <= state_5;
                                        else
                                            new_state <= state_4;    
                                        end if;

                when state_5    =>      if counter = 5 then
                                            new_state <= state_6;
                                        else
                                            new_state <= state_5;    
                                        end if;

                when state_6    =>      if counter = 6 then
                                            new_state <= state_1;
                                        else
                                            new_state <= state_6;
                                        end if;

                when others     =>      new_state <= iddle;
            end case;     
    end process;

----- Output FSM -----
    process(old_state)
        begin
            case old_state is
                when iddle      =>      PWM_A <= '0';
                                        PWM_B <= '0';
                                        PWM_C <= '0';

                when state_1    =>      PWM_A <= PWM;
                                        PWM_B <= '0';
                                        PWM_C <= '0';

                when state_2    =>      PWM_A <= PWM;
                                        PWM_B <= '0';
                                        PWM_C <= '0';

                when state_3    =>      PWM_A <= '0';
                                        PWM_B <= PWM;
                                        PWM_C <= '0';

                when state_4    =>      PWM_A <= '0';
                                        PWM_B <= PWM;
                                        PWM_C <= '0';

                when state_5    =>      PWM_A <= '0';
                                        PWM_B <= '0';
                                        PWM_C <= PWM;

                when state_6    =>      PWM_A <= '0';
                                        PWM_B <= '0';
                                        PWM_C <= PWM;

                when others     =>      PWM_A <= '0';
                                        PWM_B <= '0';
                                        PWM_C <= '0';
            end case;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

The testbench to test the program:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity TB_Mux is
end TB_Mux;

architecture Behavioral of TB_Mux is
component Mux
     port ( CLK     : in STD_LOGIC;
            RST     : in STD_LOGIC;
            PWM     : in STD_LOGIC;
            PWM_INT : in STD_LOGIC;
            PWM_A   : out STD_LOGIC;
            PWM_B   : out STD_LOGIC;
            PWM_C   : out STD_LOGIC);
end component;

signal CLK : STD_LOGIC;
signal RST : STD_LOGIC;
signal PWM : STD_LOGIC;
signal PWM_INT : STD_LOGIC;
signal PWM_A : STD_LOGIC;
signal PWM_B : STD_LOGIC;
signal PWM_C : STD_LOGIC;

constant CLK_Period : time:= 8 ns;
begin

u0:Mux
    port map( CLK => CLK,
              RST => RST,
              PWM => PWM,
              PWM_INT => PWM_INT,
              PWM_A => PWM_A,
              PWM_B => PWM_B,
              PWM_C => PWM_C);

    process
          begin
              CLK <= '0';
              wait for CLK_period/2;
              CLK <= '1';
              wait for CLK_period/2;            
      end process;

    process

        begin
            PWM     <= '0';        
            RST     <= '1';
            PWM_INT <= '0';
            wait for 5 * clk_period;
            PWM     <= '1';
            RST     <='0';
            PWM_INT <='1';
            wait for 1 * clk_period;
            PWM_INT <= '0';
            wait for 5 * clk_period;
            PWM_INT <='1';
            wait for 1 * clk_period;
            PWM_INT <= '0';
            wait for 5 * clk_period;
           PWM_INT <='1';
            wait for 1 * clk_period;
           PWM_INT <= '0';
        wait;
        end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's not working? Do you get an error during compilation? Does it not behave as you expect?

Comment: I just added the testbench. So I generate the interrupt but the outputs just stays low.

Comment: "the outputs just stay low". You can monitor the internal signals like the states in simulation, (add them to the Wave window) and see what it's really doing.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I didn't know of this trick. As I suspected, it stays in iddle mode. How come, the counter acts as it should?

Comment: I'm not debugging a 3-process state machine. The single-process form is shorter and much simpler to get right.

Answer (score 0):

Your sensitivity lists are incomplete.